# Can I build a native MacOS desktop GUI using Node.js?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm learning how to build native desktop applications but am not yet familiar with the nuances of working with the OS to create interfaces.

Because Node is easy to get started with, I am looking to it as a platform to learn on and will leverage my learnings across to other languages when I am comfortable.

I was able to build a basic application for Linux using a package that exposes "gtk-4 bindings" to Node.

My overall objective is to write my core application logic once and have multiple presentation layers using OS specific UI libraries that are loaded based on the OS that launches the application (Linux via gtk4+libadwaita, MacOS via Cocoa, Windows via... no idea yet).

My understanding is that MacOS's UI kit is called Cocoa? It seems that all the resources I see online say it's exclusive to Swift and Objective-C.

Are there no bindings for other languages?

It goes without saying, I am trying to avoid web interfaces so Electron and similar are out of the question.

Comment: Cocoa is a collection of frameworks. macOS's UI kits are called SwiftUI and AppKit.

Comment: I would recommend Qt.  It's an excellent cross-platform widget kit (and lots more) that provides native look and feel on all three major platforms.  I use it in my own big-ish cross-platform application, and although it has its annoying quirks, overall I have been tremendously pleased with it.

Answer (score -1):

No you can't. Just use React.js